# I want to get only those subset which have k elements in it

Tags: python, list

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
K=2
```

The ans i want

```
L=[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4][4,5],[5,6],[6,7]]
```

In ans there should be no subset which doesn't have k elements in it

Comment: Why is `[1, 3]` not a subset? Or do you just want a fixed length sliding window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension

```
answer = [[L[j] for j in range(i, i + K)] for i in range(len(L) - K)]
```

Comment: It will repeat the elements after first iteration not the ans what i want.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate a number starting from 0 to the maximum number from which at least `K` elements exists, then create the list of list out the items starting and ending with required indices, you can use List Comprehension to accomplish this:

```py
>>> [L[i:i+K] for i in range(len(L)-K+1)]

[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7]]
```

Comment: It will repeat the elements after 1st iteration not the desired op i want

Comment: @ABHAYPRATAP Thats exatcly what OP wanted. Look at the expected output for given List `L` and number `K`

Comment: Look at your question, the given list and the expected result